# I am getting a problem comparing two numbers with the conditional operator (?:)

Tags: java, numbers, compare, conditional-operator

public class questions {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
    int num1 = userInput.nextInt() ;
    int num2 = userInput.nextInt() ;
    
  (num1==num2) ? System.out.println("Same"): System.out.println("Not same");  // i am getting an error in that line
    
}
```

}

how can i compare these two numbers from user inputs with the conditional operator ?

Comment: You should have included the exact error or exception you saw. This helps you the people answering you.

Comment: You may really be looking for a good, old-fashioned `if`-`else` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java separates some elements of your program into *statements* and *expressions*. A *statement* is an instruction to do something, and an *expression* is code that produces some value. You can write an expression and ignore the value (`Math.sin(0);`), called an *expression statement*, but a statement on its own has no value and can't be made into an expression.

The conditional/ternary operator `?:` works only on *expressions*; that is, it's not a general flow-control tool like `if` but can only be used to select between two alternate values. Since `System.out.println` returns void (no value), it can only be called as a statement and thus can't be used as a ternary.

You can always use `if` to select between entirely different statements (usually and preferably *block statements*); if you want to use the conditional operator with `System.out.println` you must use it to select an expression to be passed to it as its argument:

```java
System.out.println(condition ? "true" : "false"); // an expression of type String
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a string response to a ternary expression with similar logic, and then print that message:

```java
int num1 = userInput.nextInt();
int num2 = userInput.nextInt();

String msg = num1 == num2  ? "Same" : "Not same";
System.out.println(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
System.out.println((num1 == num2) ? "Same" : "Not same");
```